# How to fill canny edge image in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, contour

I have an image, for example:
[image: an image of a sword with a transparent background]

I apply the Canny edge detector and get this image:
[image: output of Canny edge detection]

How do I fill this image? I want the area enclosed by the edges to be white. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can do floodfill after doing some morphology to ensure it is closed. Or you can get the contour and draw the contour as white filled on a black background. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0 and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

Comment: Why do you get the edges if you need the whole object? Why not use any of a million existing segmentation algorithms instead of Canny?

Comment: Also, your PNG image has a transparent background. All you need to do is look at the alpha channel, and you get the output that you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in Python/OpenCV by getting the contour and drawing it white filled on a black background.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('knife_edge.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get the (largest) contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background
result = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), cv2.FILLED)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('knife_edge_result.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**This doesn't answer the question.**
It is just an addition to my comment on the question, comments don't allow code and images.

---

The example image has a transparent background. Therefore, the alpha channel gives the output you're looking for. Without any knowledge of image processing, you can load the image and extract the alpha channel as follows:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('base.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
alpha = img[:,:,3]

cv2.imshow('', alpha); cv2.waitKey(0); cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: output from code above, the sword is white and the background is black]

Answer (score 1):

Similar result with morphology operations

```
img=cv2.imread('base.png',0)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
rect=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh,rect,iterations = 5)
erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, rect, iterations=4)
```

[image]