# how to fill color to specific region of image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on opencv with python. i want to detect the suits(coat) using edge detection and find all the contours and with the help of these contours i want to fill the whole suit(coat) with a specific color.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import PIL
# Read the original image
img = cv2.imread('blazer2.jpg')

scale_percent = 80  # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)

# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Convert to graycsale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Blur the image for better edge detection
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3,3), 0)
# apply threshlod to conveert the image into black and white so it will be easy to find the contour from the image


#canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
contor,herf=cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.imshow('edge detection',edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output of the canny edge detection is given below

[edge detection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpqR4.png)

Now i want to fill color inside the suits using opencv
please suggest any methods or any way through which i can do this

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67285972/how-to-fill-canny-edge-image-in-opencv-python) help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv2.drawContours to draw the contours and fill them :

```
edges = cv2.Canny(image=im, threshold1=1, threshold2=50)
contor,herf=cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv2.drawContours(edges, contor, -1, 1, thickness = -1)#draw and fill the contour with color
```

Comment: thanks for your response but 'cv2.drawContours' draw the outerline(edges) only not all the area inside of this contours. I had also tried cv2.fillploy but it also does not work

Comment: The argment ```thickness = -1``` should fill the contours as said in the docs https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc, have you tried it ?

Comment: as mentionned in the comments, it is equivalent to ```thickness = cv2.FILLED```. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67285972/how-to-fill-canny-edge-image-in-opencv-python